# Rename video with Vimeo API

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm looking to rename my videos with the Vimeo Api and Google Apps Script. I succesfully have the API moving videos into folders (using pretty much identical syntax to below) but can't for the life of me get the renaming working. It's extremely frustrating.

[Here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#edit_video) is the reference and below is my code - it just returns the video info as if I'm not trying to change anything, even though I'm clearly using a 'PATCH' call, not a 'GET'.
Where am I meant to put the 'name' parameter??

```
function renameVideo(){

  var newName = 'thisismynewname';
  var url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/_________?name=' + newName;

  var options = { 
    'method': 'PATCH',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {
      'Accept':'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
    },
    //Note that I've also tried 'name' : 'thisismynewname' here too
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(response).name); //it just returns the *current* name not the new one, and doesn't change it

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw [the official document of Edit a video](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#edit_video), it seems that `name` is included in the request body. So how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function renameVideo(){
  var newName = 'thisismynewname';
  var url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/_________';  // Modified

  var options = { 
    'method': 'PATCH',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {
      'Accept':'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
    },
    'payload': JSON.stringify({name: newName})  // Added
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(response).name);
}
```

- The content type is `application/json`.

#### Reference:

- [Edit a video](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#edit_video)

Comment: You, sir, are a champion.